# Simplify statement without using truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I can't find an appropriate law that would lead to further shortening of the equation, what would be the simplest and shortest method?

Work

$((p ∧ q) ∧ r) ∨ ((¬r ∧ p) ∧ q) ∨ ¬q\tag*{Original}$

$((p\land q)\land r)\lor (¬r\land (p\land q))\lor ¬q  \tag*{Associative law}$

$((p\land q)\land (r\lor ¬r))\lor ¬q        \tag*{Dissociation law}$

Comment: Work inside-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplification use [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence):
\begin{align}
&((p ∧ q) ∧ r) ∨ ((¬r ∧ p) ∧ q) ∨ ¬q\\
\equiv&((p ∧ q) ∧ r) ∨ (¬r ∧ (p ∧ q)) ∨ ¬q\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&((p ∧ q) ∧ r) ∨ ((p ∧ q) ∧ ¬r) ∨ ¬q\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&(p ∧ q) ∧ (r∨ ¬r) ∨ ¬q\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(p ∧ q) ∧ \top ∨ ¬q\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&(p ∧ q) ∨ ¬q\tag*{Identity law}\\
\equiv&(p∨¬q)∧(q∨¬q)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(p∨¬q)∧\top\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&~p∨¬q\tag*{Domination law}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since the original expression is something$\vee\lnot q$, when evaluating something,  you can assume $q$. Hence,  the expression simplifies to $$(p\wedge r)\vee(\lnot r\wedge p)\vee\lnot q$$This simplifies to $$p\vee\lnot q$$or more simply,  $$q\to p$$